# movie imdb get the id of the actor

Tags: python, imdb, imdbpy

I have an actor object, and it has both name and id, i could take the name, but it couldn't take the id

look please

```
>>> actor
<Person id:0000199[http] name:_Pacino, Al_>
>>> actor["name"]
u'Al Pacino'
>>> actor["id"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IMDbPY-5.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/imdb/utils.py", line 1469, in __getitem__
    rawData = self.data[key]
KeyError: 'id'
>>>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the `.personID` property of a `Person` object:

```
actor.personID
```

Comment: it work, thank you, will accept it once the system allow

Comment: how to get movie id by giving movie name